# Find the most executed section of java source code

Tags: java, profiling

I am using netbeans IDE 7.4. I want to find the lines of code that the most of running time is spent. I heard a little about profilers that can used to thread monitoring and etc... .
But I don't know  (exactly!) **how to find the section{s} of code that frequently used in my program**. *I want to find out the mechanism and equipments provided by JVM for that- not only using the third party packages(profilers and etc...)*.

Comment: see https://profiler.netbeans.org/

Comment: Asking about resources is off topic. Please ask about a specific problem you have.

Comment: VisualVM is provided in the standard JDK distribution.

Comment: It seems that the smallest section that visualVM and netbeans profiler can monitor is  **thread** .But i want to find the **most frequent lines** of code **with my own code** (without any additional packages)

Answer (score 1):

You can profile the CPU with visualVM and you 'll find which methods are CPU consumming. You have to make filter (regex) to focus on your classes.

Comment: Tnx. But it is not may answer exactly. How do i find the lines in a typical function that runs more than other lines?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose line L of your code, if removed, would cut the overall wall-clock time in its thread by 50%. Then if you, at a random time, dump the stacks of all running threads, locate your thread, and disregard all the levels that are not your code, there is a 50% chance that you will see line L in the remaining lines.

So if you do this 10 times, you will see line L about 5 times, give or take.

In fact, any line of your code, if you see it on more than one stack sample, if you can remove or bypass it, will save you a healthy fraction of time, guaranteed.
What's more, this method (while crude) will find any speedup that profilers can find, and more that they can't.

The math behind it can be found [*here.*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)

---

Example: A worker thread is spending 80% of its time doing I/O and allocating memory in the process of parsing XML to build a data structure. You can see that the XML comes from a data structure in a different piece of code in the same thread. It's big code - you wouldn't have known this without the samples pointing it out. You only have to take two or three samples before you see it twice. Just bypass the XML - 5x speedup.